# How to keep button value when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a javascript function that is triggered when a button is pressed. That function loads an external page with the values of a field.

My problem is that when I refresh the page my clicked button is reset. What I want is to keep that button value when it refreshes so it still loads that page and only reset when another button is pressed.

js code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("button.btn").click(function() {
            var tip = document.getElementById("tip5").value;
            var id_local = document.getElementById("id_local").value;
            $("#tipuri_rezervare").load("select_tip_rezervare.php?id=" + id_local + "&tip=" + tip);
        });
    });
</script>
```

php code

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
                FROM Tip_Rezervare  
                INNER JOIN Local ON Local.ID_Local=:id_local
                INNER JOIN Leg_Tip_Local ON Tip_Rezervare.ID_Tip=Leg_Tip_Local.ID_Tip and Leg_Tip_Local.ID_Local=:id_local");
$stmt->bindParam(':id_local', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute() ;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $local = $row['Denumire_Local'];
    echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="tip'.$row['ID_Tip'].'" value="'.$row['ID_Tip'].'">'.$row['Nume'].'</button>';
}   
?>
</div>

<form id="tip" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_local" id="id_local" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <div id="tipuri_rezervare"></div>
```

Comment: With a session maybe?

Comment: You will have to use some sort of storage - session variable, cookie, database - to store the value of the button and then retrieve that value on refresh.

Comment: solved with creating a session of tip on select_tip_rezervare.php and verifing it on refresh. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an Ajax call & set a session during the result fetch from external page but before page refresh and read the session values after page refreshed & set it on page.

Comment: Please do not post comments ans answers.

Comment: you can read the session value during the page is refreshed using php and set that value for button pressed